# How to embed a C application into a Java applet

Tags: java, jvm, embed, win32com

I saw that vizzed.com succeeded at embedding zSnes into a web browser. I want to do the same with another C application. Is there any folks out there who know how to do the same? I guess it's very complicated, but I need a cue or two.

Thank you.

Comment: Even if it were possible, you would lose that nice platform independence HTML provides. You would have to include multiple versions of your C part for different operating systems, 32 vs 64 bit, different browsers. And then you could have such stuff like 32bit browser on 64bit platform... ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vizzed.com doesn't use zsnes. It uses [VirtualNES](http://www.virtualnes.com/) which is a Java based emulator. You can't embed native code in a Java Applet.

The only option for calling native code would be to use JNI (Java Native Interface) but it wouldn't be sufficiently cross-platform for the web.

Comment: It seems that you didn't go far enough. On this page:
http://www.vizzed.com/play/super-mario-world-snes-online-super-nintendo-8616-game

You can open a popup where a zSnes in truly embedded in the browser window. You only have to type ESC to realize it is zSnes.

Comment: @DannyCoulombe - I did, in fact, go that far (and indeed played a bit of the game). Behavior when pressing escape doesn't mean that zsnes is embedded. It means that the Java port was done well.

Comment: Interesting. My knowledge of Java is very limited. It is possible to port a C application without having to recode the whole application? I mean, can Java understand some .c files?

Comment: @DannyCoulombe - No. You have to re-write the code. Depending on the complexity of the application, that may be easy or it may be incredibly difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java native interface(JNI), to learn JNI [click here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/)